# Powering a device through GPIO

Tags: voltage-regulator, gpio, linux

I have a custom PCB based on imx28 (primary board). It receives external power via a cable. There is another PCB (secondary board) connected via GPIO to the primary board. The secondary board doesn't have power on its own but is powered through the first board.

The primary board is running a custom Linux distribution.
Normally, the setup was to power the secondary board using one of the regulators the SoC provides. When that setup is on, I can't modify the pin because it's consumed by the regulator driver. However, now I need to be able to control the power for the secondary board programmatically. Because of that, I've removed the regulator part and am just using the pin as a generic GPIO which I export to sysfs and just turn the value to 1. That seems to power on the secondary device.

Should I be worried about the stability and power that a GPIO pin can supply (as opposed to the capabilities of a SoC regulator)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The i.MX28 datasheet says:

[image: i.MX28 GPIO current]

You have to check whether these currents are enough for your secondary board.

Please note that these limits are for the specified voltage drops; if you draw less current, the voltage will be higher than 0.8×VDDIO, and if you draw more (which is possible), the voltage will drop even more. (So it might make sense to configure "High" drive strength even if you need only 5 mA.)

Comment: So it's reasonable to expect that the GPIO will provide a much less reliable power supply that the regulator and should avoid the approach if a stable supply is needed?

Comment: The GPIOs are reliable with these currents. I don't know how much current the regulator can supply, or how much your board actually draws.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "Will this GPIO provide a less reliable power source" than a regulator is Yes, but just how reliable it needs to be is dependent on the load.

If your load is switching, then there will be noise on the GPIO source (because it has a relatively high resistance). This noise is generated by the changes in current (due to things switching) * the effective source resistance of the GPIO.